# Avoid use of a single number in a PostgreSQL 9 sequence

Tags: postgresql, sequence, postgresql-9.3, alter

Would it be possible with a sequence in Postgre to skip an Id? For example the sequence last id is 5, I want to set 7 as being used, so that the next Ids generated will be 6 then 8?

Comment: No, you can't tell a sequence to skip value in between. You can only tell it to _continue_ with a specific value.

Comment: Elaborating: You can't mark some arbitrary value in the future as used, because a sequence only has the concept of "next value". So when it's at 7, you can `nextval` to get (and discard) 8, but you can't say "skip 42 when you get to it, but keep going normally until then". You can, however, say `setval('my_seq', 43)` to start from 43.

Comment: Note that caring about specifics of sequence-generated values often indicates a design problem in your application. Sequence values can be *discarded unused* by PostgreSQL under a number of circumstances, from unclean restart to transaction abort. There is no guarantee that the sequence will go 1,2,3,4... . It might land up producing 1,3,9,44,72 as far as your app is concerned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a one time skip,

```
SELECT nextval('sequence_name');
```

This will burn an id and increment the sequence.

For doing evens only,

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_name INCREMENT BY 2;
```